# Solving ODE, with sinusoidal force and harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

OK, this is another one of those that should be simple enough to do. But maybe I am just bad at differential equations.

We have the following:

$$x''+ \gamma x'+ \omega_0^2 = 3 \cos t + 2 \sin t$$

Now, if this was just $x''+ \gamma x'+ \omega_0^2 = 3 \cos t$ I would start with a solution that took the form from the roots of the characteristic equation, which in this case is $r^2 + \gamma r + \omega_0^2$ and the roots are $\frac{-\gamma \pm \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 4 \omega_0^2}}{2}$. If the root is imaginary the solution would be 
$y=C_1e^{\frac{-\gamma}{2} t} \cos \frac{\sqrt{\gamma^2 - 4 \omega_0^2}}{2}t + C_2e^{\frac{-\gamma}{2} t} \sin \frac{\sqrt{\gamma^2 - 4 \omega_0^2}}{2}t$

and if the roots are real the solution would look like $x=C_1 e^{\frac{\sqrt{\gamma^2 - 4 \omega_0^2}}{2}t}+C_2e^{\frac{\sqrt{\gamma^2 - 4 \omega_0^2}}{2}t}$.

Or we might go with taking $x_p$, a particular solution, and going with $x_p = A \sin t + B \cos t$.

I wasn't sure how to go tho, and I am sure the latter solution is the one, but I wanted to check. I know this may sound simple enough to most people here, but I am stil feeling my way through differentials a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your homogeneous solution should be

$$x=C_1e^{\frac{-\gamma}{2} t} \cos \frac{\sqrt{4 \omega_0^2-\gamma^2 }}{2}t + C_2e^{\frac{-\gamma}{2} t} \sin \frac{\sqrt{4 \omega_0^2-\gamma^2 }}{2}t$$

The particular solution is, as you say, of the form $A \cos{t} + B \sin{t}$.  Plug this into the equation to get

$$-(A \cos{t} + B \sin{t}) + \gamma (-A \sin{t}+B \cos{t}) + \omega_0^2 (A \cos{t} + B \sin{t}) = 0$$

or

$$[(\omega_0^2-1) A + \gamma B] \cos{t} + [-\gamma A + (\omega_0^2-1) B] \sin{t} = 3 \cos{t} + 2 \sin{t}$$

which means that

$$(\omega_0^2-1) A + \gamma B=3$$
$$-\gamma A + (\omega_0^2-1) B = 2$$

Solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks! That was really stupid of me.

Comment: Btw I was just curious, why switch the terms under the square root?

Comment: Because you're using trigonometric functions, not exponentials. You write it yourself: *`If the root is imaginary the solution would be [...]'* You only make one mistake: what's underneath the square root should be *minus* the discriminant or else it's still negative and the root imaginary. Look up this fine point again in your book.

Comment: so you multiply what wold be the $b^2 - 4ac$ of the quadratic by -1, yes? I didn't see that bit anywhere i my text but I will look.